# deSolve: Can't understand how to early stop ode solver with root functions

Tags: r, ode, desolve

I am confused about how to stop the solver when a certain condition is met. I prepared a dummy SIR model that should stop once the I compartment reaches a certain value. But in my code the solver simply continues on:

```
library(deSolve)
library(dplyr)

pars <- c(beta = .1, gamma = .04)

init <- c(S = 100, I = .01, R = 0, trig = 0)

rootFun <- function(t, y, pars) {
    r <- 1
    if (y['I'] > 10 & y['trig'] == 0) r <- 0
    if (y['I'] > 80) r <- 2
    
    if (r == 2) print('should finish')
    
    return(r)
}

eventFun <- function(t, y, pars) {
    message('First threshold passed!')
    
    y['trig'] <- 1
    
    y
}

derFun <- function(t, y, pars) {
    with(as.list(c(y, pars)), {
        dS = -S * I * beta
        dI = S * I * beta - I * gamma
        dR = I * gamma
        
        list(c(dS, dI, dR, 0))
    }) 
}

ode(y = init, func = derFun, parms = pars, times = 1:100, events = list(func = eventFun, root = TRUE, terminalroot = 2),
    rootfun = rootFun) %>% invisible()
```

The solver should stop if the root evaluates to 2, trigger an event if evaluates to zero and continue in all the other cases. But instead the root being 2 does not stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event(root=>action) mechanism, the event is located at a root of a continuous function of the state. In your case, the root functions would be `y['I']-10` and `y['I']-80`, `rootfun` is the list of these functions (or the function returning the list of their values).

This function gets evaluated frequently on all parts of the solution curve to detect a **sign change** (it might also work, for some steppers, if a component is piecewise constant and the root function hits exactly zero). The interval of a sign change is then refined with a bracketing method. Apart from providing these values, no processing should and can happen in the root function.

The action on the state is encoded in `eventfun`, it returns the new state after the event. Internally, the integration is stopped at the root and restarted anew with the returned state as initial value.

Termination is encoded with the `terminalroot` variable. It is an index and determines which root function provides the termination event.

So

```
rootFun <- function(t, y, pars) {
return(c(y['I']-10, y['I']-80))
}
```

should work with all the other lines unchanged. Note that the trigger component is now unused and could be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I totally misunderstood how it should work!